# Repeating Facebook post throwing error(Bad request)c# mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on c#mvc4 project.I am trying to post messages,link,images and video to facebook via my website.I followed this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/569920/Publish-a-post-on-Facebook-wall-using-Graph-API.I am success with first posting,Secondly while posting it throws an error  bad request(400) on the code

```
  facebook.GetAccessToken(Session["facebookQueryStringValue"].ToString());
```

My code snippets are here

**Controller**

```
        Authentication auth = new Authentication();


    public ActionResult Success()
    {

      if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
            {
                string Code = Request.QueryString["code"];
                Session["facebookQueryStringValue"] = Code;
            }
            if (Session["facebookQueryStringValue"] != null)
            {

                Facebook facebook = auth.FacebookAuth();
                facebook.GetAccessToken(Session["facebookQueryStringValue"].ToString());
                FBUser currentUser = facebook.GetLoggedInUserInfo();
                IFeedPost FBpost = new FeedPost();
                if (Session["postStatus"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    FBpost.Message = Session["postStatus"].ToString();
                    facebook.PostToWall(currentUser.id.GetValueOrDefault(), FBpost);
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }

        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult PostStatus(string msg)
    {
        Session["postStatus"] = msg;


        Facebook facebook = auth.FacebookAuth();
        if (Session["facebookQueryStringValue"] == null)
        {
            string authLink = facebook.GetAuthorizationLink();
            return Json(authLink);
        }

        if (Session["facebookQueryStringValue"] != null)
        {     

            facebook.GetAccessToken(Session["facebookQueryStringValue"].ToString());
            FBUser currentUser = facebook.GetLoggedInUserInfo();                
            IFeedPost FBpost = new FeedPost();
            if (Session["postStatus"].ToString() != "")
            {
                FBpost.Message = Session["postStatus"].ToString();
                facebook.PostToWall(currentUser.id.GetValueOrDefault(), FBpost);
                Session["facebookQueryStringValue"] = "";
            }
        }
        return Json("No"); 
    }
```

**Authentication**

```
 public class Authentication
{
    public Facebook FacebookAuth()
    {
//Setting up the facebook object
        Facebook facebook = new Facebook();
        facebook.AppID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        facebook.CallBackURL = "http://localhost:8088/PostStatus/Success";
        facebook.Secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        //Setting up the permissions
        List<FBPermissions> permissions = new List<FBPermissions>() {
            FBPermissions.user_about_me, // to read about me               
            FBPermissions.user_events,
            FBPermissions.user_status,
            FBPermissions.read_stream,
            FBPermissions.friends_events,
            FBPermissions.publish_stream
        };

        //Pass the permissions object to facebook instance
        facebook.Permissions = permissions;
        return facebook;
    }
}
```

**Ajax call**

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '/PostStatus/PostStatus',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { msg: msg },
                success: function (authLink) {
                    if (authLink != 'No') {
                        // window.open(authLink, 'title', 'width=660,height=500,status=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=0,menubar=no,resizable=yes,top=60,left=320');
                        window.location.href = authLink;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Any help on this error is appreciable.I cant see any other tutorial for posting message,link,video,images on facebook in c# mvc4

Comment: did you check graph api limitations? fb may have some limitations to message count you can send in interval

Comment: graph api docs(I don't have a permission to fb in my current machine, so can't send direct link) look here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

Comment: how can i give a time limit in my application for working block of code?

Comment: setTimeout for javascript, or Thread.Sleep for c#... it depends what you are trying to do

Comment: i think it is not because of limitation.Can any one helpme?